# Measuring BJT voltages in circuit?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, audio

Using a multimeter's diode setting I see that both the base-emitter and base-collector voltages of a transistor in a powered down circuit are 0.67Vm, while reversing the probes shows OL. Voltage across C-E is 1.6, probably due to it being in the circuit and other components interfere.

How much confidence can I have that the transistor is not bad? I understand that desoldering it and then measuring would be a better indicator of its state.

For context, I have an amplifier PCB with 6 transistors on it, it produces a low output volume, and was told that one of the transistors on it may be malfunctioning and I should try desoldering them to see if anything improves.

UPDATE:
TR1, TR2, TR3 and TR4 are identical NPN, and have 0.67V across both B-E and B-C and LO when inverted.

TR5 (BC558 PNP) has 0.73V and 0.7V on B-E and B-C and OL when reversed.

TR6 (BC548 NPN) has 0.69 V on both on forward, 0L on B-C **but 1.08V on B-E** when reversed.

TR7 is a digital transistor, which from what I understand is an IC and cannot be measured as a BJT.

Comment: Show the circuit.

Comment: Pages 14 and 15 I am trying to debug why an electric piano has low volume. So far I am inclined to think it's the main board that has the problem, but I was also told to make sure the transistors here are ok. https://data2.manualslib.com/pdf5/104/10340/1033931-korg/sp200.pdf?d5bab82b522550709438da31578d5f70

Comment: What transistors in the schematics are you probing?

Comment: Yes, stupid typo, contradicting myself. Updated. So B-E and B-C are 0.67. C-E is 1.6.

Comment: TR1, TR2, TR3 and TR4 are identical transistors and all had these values.

Comment: TR1 and TR2 are related to the headphones. TR3 and TR4 are related to the non-amplified output. If the low volume is in headphones AND in the non-amplified output, chances are that the problem is somewhere before those stages (Master volume? CN6?)

Comment: The reading of CE is compatible with the resistors attached to collector: TR3 has R7 and R8, and so on. The only function of TR1, TR2, TR3 and TR4 is to shunt the signal to ground whenever the mute signal is on. Did you check this mute signal?

Comment: The mute signal is around 0.2 V when the power is on. All other voltages are as in the schematic.

Comment: I had previously disconnected the main board and put a signal from a phone's audio output to pins 1 and 3 of CN5. With external output the volume was good. Does this conclusively indicate that the problem may be on the main board (previous pages in the PDF) or could it be the phone's audio signal was more 'powerful' than what normally comes from the main board and compensated for whatever may be the problem on the output board? The phone signal was 0.58 V RMS, so wasn't that large...

Comment: Volume is attenuated on both headphone and the other outputs (aren't those amplified as well, just with another chip (IC3) ? ). What I don't understand is whether can a malfunctioning transistor in the mute circuit lower the volume instead of just muting it.

Comment: It seems to be a final stage problem, since it's alternating current signal, those 0.2V could be the reason (after all, low volume is really a "mute"). Did you tried testing CN1-5 and CN3-5 feeding those signals to another amplifier? Is there some change to this 0.2 V mute voltage when mute control / switch is turned on and off? Pg. 14 has the mute circuit, but I did not understand from where the mute control comes.

Comment: As someone who is looking at the situation from far away, I'm really puzzled just with the information that the problem is "low volume". It would be really strange if the processor were keeping producing sounds, but just at low volume. It seems that the problem is really at the output stages.

Comment: The main board also has an opamp and a few analog components before it sends the signal to the output board. The volume slider signals go back into the mainboard.

Comment: Mute control is a 10K linear stereo potentiometer that correctly reflects the slider position from 0 to 10K. I did not try testing another amplifier, just the same active speakers connected into the headphone output. (It's more or less the same on the R or L jacks). Volume is maybe half of what it used to be on speakers, and very low when headphones are connected. The strangest thing (to me at least) is that the volume slider does not seem to have a noticeable effect of output volume once past half mark (5 out of 10). It did work on the full 1-10 scale though when an external signal was used.

Comment: And there is no explicit mute control on the piano. From searching around the web I understand that muting circuits in general are there to prevent cracks when transitioning between sound on and off states. Not sure if that's the case here, and whether this part malfunctioning could simply attenuate the sound all the time.

Comment: So the TR6 has 1.08V reverse voltage on base-emitter. Could R28, R29 influence the DMM diode reading? This is with the circuit powered off.

Answer (score 1):

> "Voltage across B-E is 1.6, probably due to it being in the circuit and other components interfere."

If you turned off the power supply and there is no other voltage sources on the board (batteries, charged capacitors....), VBE cannot be more than 0.7 V... unless the transistor is damaged.

Comment: Uhh, sorry my bad. After saying b-e and b-c are both 0.67 I mistyped C-E. So it is collector-emitter voltage that is 1.6. Thanks, I've updated the post.

Comment: I would experiment with powered on board by connecting each base to ground and (through 1 k resistor) to VCC.

Comment: The various source voltage measurements I did with a powered on board. I did not check the transistors that way though...